# The "3n+1" Programming Challenge in Pythonallenge

Tags: python

I'm a Python beginner. I'm trying to solve the 3n+1 problem on UVa Online Judge. The program worked fine with the input files. However, I submitted several times but still got Runtime error.

```
import sys
def compute(i, j):
    maxCycleLength = 1
    if i <= j/2:
        k = j/2+1
    else:
        k = i

    for n in range(k, j+1):
        num = n
        cycleLength = 1
        while (num != 1):
            if num%2 != 0:
                num = 3*num+1
            else:
                num = num/2
            cycleLength += 1
        if cycleLength > maxCycleLength:
            maxCycleLength = cycleLength

    return maxCycleLength

while True:
    nums = sorted(int(x) for x in next(sys.stdin).split())
    m = compute(nums[0], nums[1])
    print("{} {} {}\n".format(nums[0], nums[1], m))
```

Comment: Please edit your question with the exact text of the error you're getting.

Comment: I'm guessing they don't want you recomputing the whole cycle length for each value. If you cache the cycle lengths as you go, you won't have to run them all to completion.

Comment: That said I expect the problem may have something to do with your `while True:` loop.  As it never ends, the program will just sit there forever waiting for input.  The grader is likely programmed to timeout after a certain period and throw an error.

Comment: `next(sys.stdin)` in a `while True` would probably better be written as `for line in sys.stdin`.

Comment: BTW, you should be using floor division (`//`) for this, not true division (`/`).

Comment: @Ryan The original code is `for line in sys.stdin` but since I got the error, I changed it. (Well, eventually, it didn't change anything)
@PM2Ringa I'll try it.

Comment: @PatrickHaugh It's an online judge so I don't have the exact text of the error. And it worked well with the input files so that's really confusing.